# How to use elGamal encryption keys in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, cryptography, sjcl

I have the following keypair created with SJCL.js on node.js

```
var keyPair = sjcl.ecc.elGamal.generateKeys(sjcl.ecc.curves.c384);
```

I understand that I need somehow elGamal in Android as well.
I want to implement a chat feature whereby every text chat to be sent will be encrypted with the public key of the receiver.

How can I use these elGamal public keys to perform an encryption (and the private key to decrypt respectively) in Android? 
So far, I have just found support for RSA keys.

Comment: Install Bouncy Castle. Possibly you'll have to use the lightweight crypto API (i.e. use the Bouncy classes directly).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: I don't think Bouncycastle supports elliptic curve ElGamal, only mod p ElGamal.

Comment: Oh, in that case I wonder how I did implement it. Probably using direct EC calculations, those are available for sure.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I do not need to create the keys in Android as they are created on node.js server. However, I need to perform encrypt and decrypt operations of the provided strings.

Comment: After having done some studies, some curves are supported in bouncycastle. https://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=362269#SupportedCurves(ECDSAandECGOST)-NIST(aliasesforSECcurves)